# How to set Thin as default in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, thin, webrick

I've been starting Thin with `thin -V start` in development.

However, I would like Thin to be the default instead of WEBrick and to be able to start it with `rails s`.

Is there a way to set Thin as the default instead of WEBrick in Rails 3?

If that's not possible, is there at least a way to start it in the test environment automatically?

Comment: Add `gem 'thin'` to your Gemfile and see if that works?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I sent a pull request on the Github repository of rack and it was accepted:
  https://github.com/rack/rack/commit/b487f02b13f42c5933aa42193ed4e1c0b90382d7

In a near future, we will be able to use Thin just by adding `gem 'thin'` to our Gemfile and starting app with `rails s`.

Note that this may be a temporary measure, however.

I chose Thin because Mongrel was not maintained currently and no other server seemed to suit as an alternative to Mongrel.

Comment: As of Rails 3.2.0.rc2, which was released yesterday, `rails s` invokes Thin when your Gemfile has `gem 'thin'` line. Yey!

Comment: Actually, `rails s` now invokes Thin even if we attempt to set WEBrick as the development default with `gem 'webrick', group: :development`. I'm using Ruby 1.9.3-p327 and Rails 3.2.12 on Debian, BTW.

Comment: @MarkDBlackwell You are right. This has been the behavior of `rack` since the era of mongrel. If you have installed the first-priority server library (currently, `thin`), the `rack` picks it up instead of WEBrick even if `Gemfile` does not contain `gem 'thin'`.

Answer (score 14):

Alternatively you could use [foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman), especially if your web applications tend to get more complicated to run (background workers, clock processes to handle scheduling, etc.)

Taking **thin** as an example, you would need to create a `Procfile` in your Rails app with the following content:

```
web: bundle exec rails server thin -p $PORT
```

Then just:

```
foreman start
```

to start your server.

Answer (score 8):

You can run rails3 with thin using `rails server thin`

See the output of `rails server -h` for more options.

Comment: it's still more typing than just rails s, but I like it.

Comment: you can use alias to short it

Comment: @LukeCowell you can still use `rails s thin`

Answer (score 4):

In Gem file use: gem 'thin' 
bundle install
then rails s it will take thin as default server for your project.